# How to load an external swf in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've encountered a problem, which drives me crazy!

I have two flash files, and I want to load the second flash file into the first after a button click.

So I have a button listener and i am jumping to a specific frame where my code is.

```
var loader_mc : Loader = new Loader();
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest("2.swf");
loader_mc.load(urlRequest);
addChild(loader_mc);
```

For debugging purpose I've labeled the frame where it get executed and made it a few seconds long with some text on the stage.

If I comment this out, after I clicked on the button it jumps to that frame and the test text is shown for a few seconds, then the movie restarts.

If I uncomment it, it seems that it loads the swf, BUT then it seems the movie restarts, pretty fast and the test text is shown. So the second swf isn't loaded. It seems it loads the first flash file and replays it, but with the test text, which is only in the end?!

Comment: put a stop(); in that frame instead of some frames with text which may or may not be long enough for the loader to finish loading the file. Better yet: add listeners to know when the loader is finished or what error happened.

Comment: did it, but nothing changed. same result. the first flash file is replaying

Comment: then add listeners to notify you about the progress. Is there anything in 2.swf which manipulates the timeline?

Comment: Can you post your file so we can debug ?

Comment: Playing with frames and `addChild()` is literally bad if you don't have a handle of the loaded resource. This is because each time the playhead of Flash reaches another keyframe, the entire contents of the previous frame is destroyed, along with your loaded SWF. So, by all means, do not use frames on the main timeline for nothing but pure animation. To solve your issue, you really need to `stop()` on the frame that does loading, and process events with handlers of `Event.COMPLETE` and `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` to find out that your SWF is loading, loaded or failed to load.